# Deletion Problem: Previous Note Appears on Adding New Note

Tags: javascript, dom, random, local-storage, addeventlistener

Facing an issue in my note app: when deleting the last note it unexpectedly reappears alongside a new onee and work normally with other positions, currently a workaround using `location.reload()` after deletion is in place, but it disrupts the user interface Seeking a refined solution to prevent the deleted note from rendering with the new one upon addition

```js
class Note {
    constructor(title, content, date, tag) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.date = date;

        this.id =
            Date.now().toString() + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);

        this.tag = tag;
        this.isPined = false;
    }
}
class NoteList {
    constructor() {
        this.notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")) || [];
    }
    saveToLocalStorage() {
        localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(this.notes));
    }

    add(note) {
        this.notes.push(note);
        this.saveToLocalStorage();
    }

    remove(note) {
        const index = this.notes.indexOf(note);
        if (index !== -1) {
            this.notes.splice(index, 1);
            this.saveToLocalStorage();
        }
    }

    edit(note, title, content) {
        note.title = title;
        note.content = content;
        this.saveToLocalStorage();
    }
    getAllNotes() {
        return this.notes;
    }
}
const Elements = {
    firstPage: document.querySelector(".first-page"),
    noteHead: document.querySelector(".note-head"),
    noteTitle: document.querySelector(".note-title-input"),
    noteArea: document.querySelector(".note-text"),
    notesCard: document.getElementById("notes-card"),
    tag: document.querySelector(".note-tags-input"),
    submitBtn: document.querySelector(".submit-btn"),
    noteheading: document.querySelector(".note-heading"),
    noteresumé: document.querySelector(".note-resumé"),
    noteTagsInput: document.querySelector(".note-tags-input"),
    noteTextInput: document.querySelector(".note-text"),
};
function noItems() {
    if (notesCard.childElementCount > 0) {
        notesCard.classList.remove("no-items");
        notesCard.classList.add("items");
        if (notesCard.contains(p)) {
            notesCard.removeChild(p);
        }
    } else {
        notesCard.classList.remove("items");
        notesCard.classList.add("no-items");
        p.textContent = "No notes added yet!";
        notesCard.appendChild(p);
    }
}
const p = document.createElement("p");
const notesCard = document.querySelector("#notes-card");
function cardNote(note) {
    // Create card container
    const cardDiv = document.createElement("div");
    cardDiv.classList.add("card");
    cardDiv.setAttribute("id", note.id);

    // Create icon
    const icon = document.createElement("i");
    icon.classList.add("fa-solid", "fa-bars");

    // Create tag
    const tig = document.createElement("span");
    tig.innerHTML = note.tag;

    tig.innerText.length > 0 ? tig.classList.add("show") : false;
    const tagIconDiv = document.createElement("div");
    tagIconDiv.classList.add("tag-icon");
    const deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
    deleteButton.classList.add("delete-btn");
    deleteButton.innerHTML = `<i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>`;
    tagIconDiv.append(icon, tig, deleteButton);
    cardDiv.appendChild(tagIconDiv);

    // Create content container
    const contentDiv = document.createElement("div");

    // Create and append title
    const noteTitle = document.createElement("h2");
    noteTitle.classList.add("note-heading");
    noteTitle.innerHTML = note.title;

    // Create and append truncated content
    const noteContent = document.createElement("h5");
    const truncatedContent = note.content.slice(0, 35);

    noteContent.innerHTML = truncatedContent + "...";
    noteContent.classList.add("note-resumé");

    // Create and append date
    const noteDate = document.createElement("p");
    noteDate.classList.add("note-date");
    noteDate.innerHTML = note.date;

    // Append title, truncated content, and date to contentDiv
    contentDiv.append(noteTitle, noteContent, noteDate);

    // Append contentDiv to cardDiv
    cardDiv.appendChild(contentDiv);

    // Append cardDiv to notesCard
    notesCard.appendChild(cardDiv);

    // Create and append horizontal line
}
function renderNotes(notelist) {
    notesCard.innerHTML = "";

    notelist.getAllNotes().forEach((note) => {
        cardNote(note);
    });
}
function setupEventListeners() {
    const noteList = new NoteList(); // Create NoteList instance

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        const save = document.querySelector(".submit-btn");
        const noteTitle = document.querySelector(".note-title-input");
        const noteText = document.querySelector(".note-text");
        const noteTags = document.querySelector(".note-tags-input");

        save.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            if (!noteText.value) return e.preventDefault();
            const currentDate = new Date();

            const options = {
                weekday: "long",
                year: "numeric",
                month: "short",
                day: "numeric",
                hour: "numeric",
                minute: "numeric",
            };
            let date = currentDate.toLocaleString("en-us", options);

            const note = new Note(
                noteTitle.value,
                noteText.value,
                date,
                noteTags.value
            );

            noteList.add(note);

            // Update cardNote function to handle the new NoteList structure
            cardNote(note);
            // Clear input fields after adding a note
            (noteText.value = ""),
                (noteTags.value = ""),
                (noteTitle.value = "New Note");
            noItems();
        });
        renderNotes(noteList);
        noItems();
    });
}

function displayNoteInputs(welcomeNote) {
    Elements.noteTitle.value = welcomeNote.title;
    Elements.noteArea.placeholder = welcomeNote.content;
    if ((Elements.firstPage.style.display = "block")) {
        Elements.noteHead.style.display = "block";
        Elements.firstPage.style.display = "none";
    } else if ((Elements.firstPage.style.display = "none")) {
        Elements.noteHead.style.display = "none";
        Elements.firstPage.style.display = "block";
    }
    (Elements.noteArea.value = ""),
        (Elements.noteTagsInput.value = ""),
        (Elements.noteTitle.value = "New Note");
}
function reviewNote() {
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        const notesCard = document.getElementById("notes-card");

        // Use event delegation on the parent element (notesCard)
        notesCard.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            const card = e.target.closest(".card");

            e.preventDefault();
            if (!card) {
                return;
            }

            const notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));
            const me = notes.find((note) => note.id === card.id);
            Elements.firstPage.style.display = "none";
            Elements.noteHead.style.display = "block";
            Elements.noteArea.value = me.content;
            Elements.noteTitle.value = me.title;
            Elements.tag.value = me.tag;
        });
    });
}

const addBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-add-note");
function insertNoteInput(Note, NoteList) {
    addBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const welcomeNote = new Note(
            "New Note",
            "Start typing here...",
            new Date().toLocaleString()
        );
        const noteList = new NoteList();
        displayNoteInputs(welcomeNote);
        // The setTimeout function is used to focus on the note-text input field
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById("note-text").focus();
        }, 0);
        // Add the welcome note to the noteList only if the user has add a new note
        welcomeNote.content !== "Start typing here..." &&
        welcomeNote.title !== "New Note"
            ? noteList.add(welcomeNote)
            : false;
    });
}
function deleteCardEventListener() {
    const notesCard = document.getElementById("notes-card");

    notesCard.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        const deleteBtn = e.target.closest(".delete-btn");
        if (deleteBtn) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const card = deleteBtn.closest(".card");

            if (!card) {
                return;
            }

            const notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));
            const me = notes.find((note) => note.id === card.id);
            const index = notes.indexOf(me);

            if (index !== -1) {
                notes.splice(index, 1);
                localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes));
            }

            card.remove();
            /*  window.location.reload(); */
            noItems();
        }
    });
}

setupEventListeners();
insertNoteInput(Note, NoteList);
deleteCardEventListener();
reviewNote(Elements);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit:wght@200;400;500;600&display=swap");
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    --myPurple: #5e548e;
    --myBlack: #333333;
    --lightPurple: #8972b6;
    --mygreen:#496f5d;
    --mylightgreen:#62a87c;
}

body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 40px 350px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 100vh;
    grid-template-areas: "side-bar left-section right-section";
}
.side-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 2rem;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: var(--myBlack);
    font-size: 30px;
    border-right: 2px solid var(--myPurple);
}

.side-bar > i:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 20px var(--myBlack);
    color: var(--lightPurple);
    transform: translateY(-7px);
}
.side-bar > i {
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px var(--myBlack);
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.col-12 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 8px;
}

.whereiam {
    color: var(--myBlack);
    font-size: 28px;
}

.btn-add-note {
    color: var(--myPurple);
    font-size: 33px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.btn-add-note:hover {
    color: var(--lightPurple);
}

.search-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.search-input {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0.4em 1em;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: white;
    background-color: var(--myBlack);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
}

.search-input::placeholder {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.search-input:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1rem var(--myPurple);
}

.container {

    padding-bottom: 1.2rem;
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--myPurple);
}
.left-section {
    border-right: #5e548e 3px solid;
    font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 100vh;
}

.no-items {
    height: 70%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: var(--myPurple);
    font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
}
.items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: var(--myBlack);
    font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 70%;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}
.fa-bars {
    font-size: 28px;
    color: var(--myPurple);
    cursor: pointer;

    height: 100%;
}
.card {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: start;
    gap: 1rem;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-bottom:15px  ;
    border-bottom: 3px solid var(--myPurple);   

}
.hrByMe {
    border: 1px solid var(--myPurple);
    width: 100%;
}
.right-section {
    font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100vh;
}
.note-title-input {
    font-size: 27px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    outline: none;
    font-family: "kanit", sans-serif;
}
.uppernote {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1rem;
    font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--myPurple);
}
.note-tags-input {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 50%;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    outline: none;
    font-family: "kanit", sans-serif;
}


.submit-btn,
#delete,
.pin {
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.submit-btn {
    background-image: url(./images/icons8-vérifié-48.png);
}

#delete {
    background-image: url(./images/icons8-poubelle-50.png);
}

.pin {
    background-image: url(./images/broche.png);
}

/* Button Hover Styles */
.pin:hover {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.submit-btn:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
#delete:hover {
    animation: shake 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes shake {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    25% {
        transform: rotate(15deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(-15deg);
    }
    75% {
        transform: rotate(15deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}

.note-area {
    padding: 1rem 2rem 0 2rem;
    height: 100%;
}
textarea {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    resize: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
}

.arrow {
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    rotate: 243deg;
    padding: 1rem;
    pointer-events: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.quote {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: var(--myPurple);
    font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 47%;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.note-head {
    display: none;
}
.first-page {
    display: block;
}
.note-date {
    font-size: 15px;
}
.show{
    display: block;
    color: var(--myBlack);
    font-size: 13px;
    border-radius:2px; 
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: var(--mylightgreen); 
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tag-icon{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
.delete-btn {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.08, 0.83, 0.67);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px;
}

.delete-btn:hover {
    background-color: rgb(255, 69, 69);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Note</title>
        <script
            src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2399160396.js"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./images/t.png" />
        <script src="main.js" defer></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="123.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <section class="side-bar">
            <i class="fa-regular fa-note-sticky"></i>
            <!--             <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fa-regular fa-trash-can binBtn"></i> -->
        </section>
        <!--  -->
        <!--  -->
        <!--  -->
        <section class="left-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <i
                            class="fa-regular fa-note-sticky"
                            style="font-size: 25px; color: lightslategray"
                        ></i>
                        <h3 class="whereiam">Notes</h3>
                    </div>
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus btn-add-note"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="search-bar">
                    <input
                        type="search"
                        class="search-input"
                        placeholder="search"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="notes-card" class="no-items"></div>
        </section>

        <section class="right-section">
            <div class="first-page">
                <img src="./images/pngegg (1).png" class="arrow" alt="" />

                <p class="quote">
                    <i>
                        Either write something worth reading or do something
                        worth writing.
                    </i>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="note-head">
                <form action="index.js" method="post">
                    <div class="uppernote">
                        <div>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                class="note-title-input"
                                value=""
                            />
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                class="note-tags-input"
                                placeholder="tags"
                                maxlength="15"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="button" id="delete" value="" />
                            <input type="button" class="pin" value="" />
                            <!-- <img src="./images/broche.png" alt="pin" class="pin" /> -->
                            <input type="button" class="submit-btn" />

                            <!--         <img src="./images/icons8-vérifié-48.png" /> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="note-area">
                        <textarea
                            name="note-area"
                            id="note-text"
                            class="note-text"
                        ></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say "deleting the last note", do you mean you're deleting the only remaining note, or do you mean the last note in the list of notes?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar if there was only a single note yes  and else  if there is  note1  note 2  note 3 delete the  note3 and add note4 you will see note1 note2 note4 and  the 3 renders when you refresh the page,  SO local storage deletes the note3 but add it with  the  new note  and  render it when refresh    sorry about my English

Comment: Probably not the problem, but you can combine `find()` and `indexOf()` with `findIndex()`.

Comment: But if you delete note2 there's no problem? I can't see anything in the code that would treat the last note specially.

Comment: @Barmar yes if you delete  the note2  no problem appear

Comment: @Barmar  i edited the post  you can check all the code now

Comment: Since local storage doesn't work in stack snippets, I copied to jsfiddle. I also changed the buttons to use text, since the image links don't work. https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/21ztc9wh/4/show

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the code for the delete button doesn't call `notelist.remove()`. You shouldn't have the code for updating local storage in two places.

Comment: so  what should i do  still haven't gotten it from the earlier day  i can't figure out where is the  problem @Barmar

Comment: I think you need to clean up all the code so you use the proper interfaces. Everything that manipulates the list of notes should go through the NoteList class. Otherwise you have multiple arrays being managed, saved and loaded from local storage, etc. The whole point of the NoteList class is to modularize it, and you're ignoring it.

Comment: Sorry but a rewrite like this is more work than I'm willing to do in an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! That code took me 3 days cuz am a beginner and i think the best solution like you say clean all my code and use the notelist more, your guidance was super helpful. appreciate it!" @Barmar